# Pointing Cromwell to local EBS mounted storage on AWS Batch

Tags: rna-seq, genomics, wdl, gtex, aws

I'm trying to run the WDL tasks from the [GTEx RNA-Seq pipeline](https://github.com/broadinstitute/gtex-pipeline) with Cromwell using AWS Batch as a backend.

I store the STAR alignment index on an Elastic Block Store since my Cromwell server instance lacks sufficient disk space. The EBS Block is mounted to my Cromwell server at `/data`. The STAR index is located at `/data/genomic-references/rnaseq/star_index_oh50`.

Try as I might, I cannot get Cromwell to run the STAR task correctly.

My JSON inputs file:

```
 {
   "rnaseq_pipeline_fastq_workflow.prefix": "s3://mybucket/test/CL100148068",
   "rnaseq_pipeline_fastq_workflow.star.fastq1": "s3://anotherbucket/genotypedata/sample1.fq.gz",
   "rnaseq_pipeline_fastq_workflow.star.star_index": "/data/genomic-references/rnaseq/star_index_oh50/",
   "rnaseq_pipeline_fastq_workflow.star.memory": "32",
   "rnaseq_pipeline_fastq_workflow.star.num_threads": "4",
   "rnaseq_pipeline_fastq_workflow.star.disk_space": "200",
   "rnaseq_pipeline_fastq_workflow.star.num_preempt": "0" 
 }
```

Error message:

```
tar: /data/genomic-references/rnaseq/star_index_oh50/: Cannot open: No such file or directory
```

Note that `/data/genomic-references/rnaseq/star_index_oh50/` does exist and is readable.

The relevant command in the GTEx container is [here](https://github.com/broadinstitute/gtex-pipeline/blob/b53b734a9b096caed237952b34cbce88b38485bd/rnaseq/star.wdl#L69):

```
tar -xvvf ${star_index} -C star_index --strip-components=1
```

If the files are stored locally, then why does `tar` fail to wrap the directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somebody helped me with this one through other channels, but I wanted to make it publicly available:

Make a tarball of the STAR index. The option `--strip-components=1` strips the first level of the path from the untarred items; thus, the expected tarball was made with something like

```
tar -cvf ${star_index} the_star_index_directory/
```

Then point Cromwell/WDL to the tarball, e.g. on S3. The GTEx container will unwrap the tarball on the fly during execution.